# My div goes out from the website width?

Tags: html, css

[image: as you can see in picture, my div goes of the range of my website, / Orange color, and i have given my site to me 100 % width, but every time i make a div, it goes of the range.]

im a new coder, i dont know why every time i make a div or class, it automatic makes my website to more width. i have set the position to be relative...

i hope you guys understand it

```css
html,body { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

h3#hvemerjeg{
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
}

h3#hvorformulti {
}

h1{ 
        text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
        color: black;
        display: block;
        top: -32px;
  font-family: fantasy; 
 }
p#infotekst {
        text-align: center;
        width: 20%;
        font-size: 15px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 1%;
        left: 10%;
        border-style:hidden;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: #ff5050;
}
#multitekst {
        text-align: center;
        width: 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
        font-size: 15px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 1%;
        left: 30%;
        top: -340px;
        border-style:hidden;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: #ff5050;
    
}
a { text-decoration: none;
 
}

#logohead {
 position:absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
 width: 12%;
 
 
}
.sect { 
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-size:cover; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.subSection { 
        height: 450px;
        background-color: white;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.sectOne {
        background-image: url(image/forside.png);
    
}
.sectTwo {
        background-color: aqua;
    
}
   
.sectThree {
    
    
}
footer {
 background-color: black; 
 color: white; 
 overflow:auto; 
 padding-bottom: 1%; 
    height:10%;
}
#footerlogo {
 padding: 1%;  
 padding-left: 3%; 
 display:block; 
 float: left; 
}
.footertekst {
 font-family: 'Trirong', serif;
 padding-left: 30%; 
 float:right;  
 font-size: 15px; 
 position: absolute; 
}

.socialemedier {
 position:relative; 
 padding-left: 75%; 
 display: block;  
}

.ikoner {
 padding-left: 5%; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> MultimediaDesigner Hamzeh Khan </title>
<meta name="description" content="Jeg Hamzeh Khan, studere multimediadesigner på århus erhvervsakademi på 1 semester, gennem uddannelse vil jeg få et større forståelse indenfor det digitale verden, og konsturere dem videre til virkeligheden">
<meta name="author" content=" Made by Hamzeh Khan">    
<meta name="keywords" content=" Design, multimediadesigner, konceptudvikler, webdesign">   
    
<head>        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Jeg Hamzeh Khan, studere multimediadesigner på århus erhvervsakademi på 1 semester, gennem uddannelse vil jeg få et større forståelse indenfor det digitale verden, og konsturere dem videre til virkeligheden">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        
</head>  
<header>   
    </header>    
<style>         
    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;        
    }

 p {
  text-align: center; 
 }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#000000;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: grey;
}

.active {
    background-color:#FF5050;
}
    
</style> 
    
<body>
    <a href="index.html">
    <img id="logohead" src="image/logokhan.png" alt="headlogo" style="width:10%;height:30px;border:3%">
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="mywork.html">Mywork</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

           
        <div class="sect sectOne">

<article>

</article>
    
    </div>

                  <div class="subSection"> 
                    <br>
                    <h1> test 1 1  </h1>
                          <h3 id="hvemerjeg"> Hvem er jeg ? </h3>
                          <p id="infotekst">
                            Jeg hedder Hamzeh Seyed og studere multimediadesign på 1 semester på Erhvervsakademi i Århus. Jeg er 22 år gammel, og bor i Kolding sammen med en Roomie og pendler til skolen hverdag kl. 05.30 om morgen. Jeg har store forventninger til mig selv ifølge uddannelsen og vil derfor gennem de næste 3 næste semester vil jeg få et langt større forståelse indenfor den digitale verden end jeg har nu.

                        I min fritid er jeg for det meste sammen med mine nærmeste omgivelser, og bruger det meste af tiden på at optage video og tager masser billeder, primært af naturen.   
                              
                              
                          </p>
                          
                           <h3 id="hvorformulti"> Hvorfor Multimedia Design </h3>
                           <p id="multitekst"> 
                        Af baggrund af de uddannelser jeg var været igennem, så føler jeg mig meget til rette i den uddannelse jeg læser nu, da jeg er den kreative/innovative person der har forståelse i den teknologis verden, og mener at der er meget jeg kan byde ind på. 

                        Når det gælder om design, er jeg den person der godt kan lide at tænke ud af boksen, og improvisere noget der ikke findes. 
                        Jeg bruger meget af min tid bag computer, hvor jeg kommer ind på nye hjemmeside hver eneste dag, og lære indtil hvordan deres struktur egentlig er, og hvordan det kan videreudvikles til noget bedre.  
                          </p>
                          
                          
    </div>
                          
                          </p>
                 
                    <div class="sect sectTwo"> 
 
 </div>
    
       <footer>
 <img id="footerlogo" src="image/KhanDESIGN.png" alt="headlogo" style="width:5%;height:10%;">
 <div>
  <br>
  <h4 class="footertekst"> Kontaktes på </h4>
 </div>
 
 <div class="socialemedier">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hamzeh.iipp"><img class="ikoner" src="image/facebookicon.png" alt="facebookicon" style="width: 10%;"></a> 
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/khaain/"><img class="ikoner" src="image/instagramicon.png"  alt="instagramicon
            "style="width: 10%;"></a>
  <a class="tooltip" href="mailto:hslipp@hotmail.com"><img class="ikoner" src="image/mailicon.png" alt="mailicon" style="width: 10%;"><span class="tooltiptext"></span></a>
   

 

<br>    
<br> 
<br>    
<br>   
    

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see in picture, my div goes of the range of my website, / Orange color, and i have given my site to me 100 % width, but every time i make a div, it goes of the range. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWChq.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWChq.png)

im a new coder, i dont know why every time i make a div or class, it automatic makes my website to more width. i have set the position to be relative

Comment: Could you please add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see whats going on?

Comment: No, add the code to the **question**, not jsfiddle.

Comment: its now posted guys

Comment: better now... ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the only problem but you did forget to close your last div.

Comment: Nope thats not the problem, hmmm

Comment: can it maybe be something with my padding, or margin ? i still dont know, i been searching for this problem in a couple of days with out any luck :/ hmm

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning? It's causing your mess.. What you are after can be achieved with relative positioning and would save you a lot of headache

Comment: i haven't used absolute position in my div, but relative, and i just found out that, its a bad idea to use relative,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens, is that you created a naturally positioned block element (#hvemerjeg).

When you move the element around using position:relative, this element (#hvemerjeg) goes out of page and creates horizontal scrollbar.

Orange area shows that as block elements have by default parent's width, when you limit their width, this extra width is shown as margin (orange). (This is just as they are shown, not related to your problem really.)

One solution to this would be to set "width: calc( 100% - 200px );" to this element.

Other solution would be to set overflow-x: hidden; to parent element of this element.

In general, using relative positioning to make page layout, is a very bad idea :)

Comment: ohh i see, i already have tried the the overflow-x: hidden, but still didnt get any result... 
but what would be a good idea to use, i have a div/img/class that i want it to be in a specific position on the website ? 

instead of using relative position, which do you prefer to use ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed typos and wording :)

Comment: You can use absolute, if this has to be on top or bottom etc of page.

If you want to create columns, the simplest way would be to create inline-blocks with "width: 20%;" and "vertical-align: top;" and put them inside a div.